# Mongo query find top sellers from array

Tags: mongodb

I'm pretty new to Mongo, I'm having trouble figure out how to write this query.  I have an order collection that looks like this.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51fade5b8c825bb19d9ef228"),
"o_id" : 1,
...
"order_line" : [
    {
            "ol_id" : 1,
            "ol_o_id" : 1,
            "ol_i_id" : 531,
            "ol_qty" : 280
    },
    {
            "ol_id" : 2,
            "ol_o_id" : 1,
            "ol_i_id" : 90,
            "ol_qty" : 295
    },
    {
            "ol_id" : 3,
            "ol_o_id" : 1,
            "ol_i_id" : 963,
            "ol_qty" : 184
    }
]}
```

I need to find the top selling related items for each item.

The query needs to find the top 5 items/ol_i_id's that are sold WITH the ol_i_id that is currently being queried.  In order to do so the query would need to find all orders with the "ol_i_id" in question, say "ol_i_id" : 531, then sum the "ol_qty" of each item sold with "ol_i_id" : 531 over the entire collection. Then report back with with the top 5 "ol_i_id" that are sold with "ol_i_id":531.

I tried to make that as understandable as possible.

/edit
So far I have this.

```
 db.orders.aggregate( { $match : { order_line: { $elemMatch : { ol_i_id : 531 } } } },
   { $project : { o_id : 1, order_line : 1} },
   { $unwind: "$order_line"},
   { $limit : 5 } )
```

Which unwinds the order_line 's to look like this.

```
   "result" : [
           {
                   "_id" : ObjectId("51fade5b8c825bb19d9ef389
                   "o_id" : 354,
                   "order_line" : {
                           "ol_id" : 1,
                           "ol_o_id" : 354,
                           "ol_i_id" : 2,
                           "ol_qty" : 271
                   }
           },
           {
                   "_id" : ObjectId("51fade5b8c825bb19d9ef389
                   "o_id" : 354,
                   "order_line" : {
                           "ol_id" : 2,
                           "ol_o_id" : 354,
                           "ol_i_id" : 707,
                           "ol_qty" : 138
                   }
           }...
```

That query just gave me all the order_lines that we purchased with the ol_i_id in question, 531.  Now I need to sum the ol_qty field for each unique ol_i_id and come back with the top 5.  This would be analogous to something you might see on amazon where it says 'people who bought this also bought this other thing'   Hope that makes more sense.  Sorry for being overly verbose on this.

Ideally, I would want it to come back with a set like this

```
 {
    "result" : [
            {
                    "ol_i_id" : 46,
                    "totalSoldWithItem531" : 20012
            },
            {
                    "ol_i_id" : 669,
                    "totalSoldWithItem531" : 19000
            },
            {
                    "ol_i_id" : 5,
                    "totalSoldWithItem531" : 18291
            },
            {
                    "ol_i_id" : 881,
                    "totalSoldWithItem531" : 18101
            },
            {
                    "ol_i_id" : 538,
                    "totalSoldWithItem531" : 17001
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

/edit I have come up with this now which is almost what I need.

```
 db.orders.aggregate( { $match : { order_line: { $elemMatch : { ol_i_id : 531 } } } },
    { $project : { o_id : 1, order_line : 1} },
    { $unwind: "$order_line"},
    { $group : { _id : "$order_line.ol_i_id", 
     totalSales : { $sum : "$order_line.ol_qty" } } },
    { $sort : { totalSales : -1 } },
    { $limit : 5 } )
```

Results look like this.

```
 {
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 531,
                    "totalSales" : 10639
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 655,
                    "totalSales" : 520
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "totalSales" : 500
            },
             ....
```

My last problem is how would I exclude item that was queried from the result set since I'm not interested in that figure?  In this case I need to exclude the _id : 531 from the results since that was the id that was queried.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, "the top 5 "ol_i_id" that are sold with "ol_i_id":531" would mean... er... 531 and what more?

Comment: Have you tried the aggregation framework? Could you show your attempts please?

Comment: @WiredPrairie So far I have this. `code` db.orders.aggregate( { $match : { ol_i_id: 2} }, 
{ order_line :  
{$project : { o_id : 1, order_line : 1} }, 
{ $unwind: "$order_line" } ) `code` Well that post didn't work as expected.

Comment: Could you please edit the question to include the details? It's still difficult to understand what you're looking for given the field names and data. (Given that field name lengths matter in MongoDB/BSON, you might consider dropping the `"ol"` prefix for example)

Comment: @WiredPrairie I agree the field names are not ideal.  Changing them at this point is not really an option.   Hope my edits have clarified my question. Thank you.

Comment: Match all orders with same item. Unwind items ordered. Group on product and sum qunatity. Sort on sum. Limit to 5? (Sorry, I don't have time to set up test data and try my plan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got most of the answer yourself, basically there are two ways to exclude the original item you were basing your query on.  One is to simply add `{$match:{_id:{$ne:origID}}}` to the end of the pipeline.  Don't forget to change `$limit:5` to `$limit:6` though, since you want to be left with five items after excluding the item itself.

A simpler way would be to add that same `{$match}` much earlier in the pipeline - in particular back after the `$unwind`.  The entire pipeline (with some simplifications) should look like this:

```
db.orders.aggregate( 
    { $match   : { "order_line.ol_i_id" : 531 } } } },
    { $project : { "order_line" : 1, _id:0 } },
    { $unwind  : "$order_line"},
    { $match   : { "order_line.ol_i_id":{"$ne": 531 } } },
    { $group   : { _id : "$order_line.ol_i_id", 
                   totalSales : { $sum : "$order_line.ol_qty" } } },
    { $sort    : { totalSales : -1 } },
    { $limit   : 5 } 
);
```